# Documents.Add fails on ASP.NET (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I am having an issue with opening a document using Microsoft Word from [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework).

This works perfectly on my developer machine, but not when deployed to [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services).

```
Dim word = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

'This line is failing to return a document object
Dim letter = word.Documents.Add(letter_doc_path)

'This line then fails due to [letter] being null
letter.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(csvPath)
```

I have added permissions in "Component Services" (dcomcnfg) to the NETWORK SERVICE user which allows the creation of the Word object in the first place, but I am completely stuck as what to do with this one.

I have also tried suppressing Word dialogs with the following line just in case

```
word.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
```

The issue isn't helped by not having an error (apart from the null object reference obviously) - maybe there's a way to query Word for a specific error message?

Comment: Does it maybe need permission to create temp files?

Comment: @StingyJack - I thought this too and it may well be related but after the 2nd line it actually creates the ~docname.doc temp file as though the document is open (and the word process's memory increases as though the doc is open)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word requires the **normal.dot** template file when opening any document, the problem was occurring because the IIS user didn't have anywhere to create the normal.dot so it was failing in the background.

This was fixed by setting the **UserTemplate path** for the newly created word instance (immediately after creating it).

The path must be writeable by the IIS user (NETWORK SERVICE in my case).

```
word.Options.DefaultFilePath(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultFilePath.wdUserTemplatesPath) = working_folder
```

So just for completeness, here's the original example with the winning line included:

```
Dim word = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

'this line fixed it
word.Options.DefaultFilePath(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultFilePath.wdUserTemplatesPath) = working_folder

Dim letter = word.Documents.Add(letter_doc_path)
```

Comment: Great to hear you worked this out and documented as well. +1. You can go ahead and accept your own answer with the hollow checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you catching the errors.

Please take a look at the following pages if you find some clue from that.

- *[Error while using Microsoft Office 2003 in web application](http://forums.asp.net/t/1522345.aspx/1?Error%20while%20using%20Microsoft%20Office%202003%20in%20web%20application)*
- *[Error while calling MS-Word from ASP.NET](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/60f72ed9-1d2d-49e8-9727-9b685ee0725e/)*
- *["There is insufficient memory or disk space. Save the document now" - Opening MS Word from ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MS-Word_From_ASPNET.aspx)*

Comment: Hi, I'm "catching the errors" using a try/catch block which throws "Object variable or with block variable not set" on the 3rd line due to the Documents.Add having failed with no error. I'm afraid none of those links provide any assistance with this problem either - thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and the settings that wheelibin suggested weren't enough to create documents using the NETWORK SERVICE account.

What I ended up doing is:

- Create a user account for this
  process to run under.
- Login as the user and run Word (this
  does various setup tasks in Word so
  the application doesn't try putting
  up modal dialogs when running as a
  service).
- Create a new application pool and set
  the pool to run as the user account.

If you're using Windows
   Authentication, and your server is
   Windows 2003 (or 2000, presumably),
   then [this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871179/en-us) applies, and you
   need to either change the SPN of the
   server, which will break Windows
   Authentication for any application
   running under a different user
   account, or you have to switch the
   authentication provider over to NTLM
   instead of Kerberos.

IIS 7 can use Kernel Mode Authentication to avoid the issue.