# Document is null when trying to add to Word Application object using Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

This code works fine when debugging in Visual Studio, but once published to IIS, document is always null.

```
templatePath = __templatePathParameter;

object objTrue = true;

wordApplication= new Word.Application();

document = wordAplication.Documents.Add(ref templatePath, ref objEmpty, ref objEmpty, ref objTrue);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Something related to the templatePath, maybe?

Comment: maybe any exceptions occurs?

Comment: see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417048/documents-add-fails-asp-net-vb-net